# Open edebug window with predefined height in Emacs

Tags: emacs, elisp

How can I open the `edebug` window in a given height? I know there is a `window-resize` function. But I am not sure if there is a hook that can be run after edebug has been activated.

Suppose I open Emacs with a file `"t.txt"` and then switch to `*scratch*` buffer and enter

```
(defun test ()
  (message "Hello"))
```

Then I instrument this function using <kbd>C-u C-M-x</kbd> (it calls `edebug-defun`), then switch to the `t.txt` buffer and type <kbd>M-: (test)</kbd> I then get following screen shot:

[image]

So by default, the `edebug` window splits the current window into two, one above the other, and activates in the lower window.

I would like to set a predefined height to this window..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a piece of advice:

```
(defadvice edebug-pop-to-buffer (after edebug-advice activate)
  "Resize window."
  (set-window-text-height (get-buffer-window buffer) 5))
```

Comment: Thanks! Seems to work perfectly. By the way, what is meant by the argument to `get-buffer-window`? That is: `buffer`.. Is this a global variable?

Comment: `buffer` is the argument of function `edebug-pop-to-buffer`.
You can look it up with `f1 f`.